# Rails Ajax render of partial with id

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm creating a simple voting partial, but it doesn't update because of this:

**error**

```
NameError - undefined local variable or method `scribble' for 
  app/views/scribbles/vote.js.erb:1:in `_app_views_scribbles_vote_js_erb
```

The only voting methods work without any issues, but it just doesn't update in the view because of the error above. I guess I just need to know how to pass the **scribble** object into vote.js.erb ???

**_vote.html.erb**

```
<%if current_user.voted_for?(scribble)%>
<a href="" id="vote_<%=scribble.id%>" name="promote" class="votes">
<div class="scribblevote"> 
    <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i>  
    <%=scribble.votes.count%> <%= link_to "demote", vote_scribble_path(:id => scribble.id, :vote => false), remote: true, method: :post%> 
    </div></a>
<%else%>
<a href="" id="vote_<%=scribble.id%>" name="promote" class="votes">
<div class="scribblevote"> 
    <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i>  
    <%=scribble.votes.count%> <%= link_to "promote", vote_scribble_path(:id => scribble.id, :vote => true), remote: true, method: :post%> 
    </div></a>
<%end%>
```

**vote.js.erb**

```
   $("#vote_<%=scribble.id%>").html("<%= escape_javascript( render(:partial => "scribbles/vote") ) %>");
```

**controller method**

```
  def vote
  @scribble = Scribble.find(params[:scribble_id])
  @vote = params[:vote]
  if @vote == "true"
    @v = :up
  else
    @v = :down
    current_user.unvote_for(@scribble)
  end
  current_user.vote(@scribble, :direction => @v)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js{}
    end
```

**scribble/_scribbles.html.erb**

```
 <% @scribbles.each do |scribble| %>
 <%= render :partial=> "scribbles/vote", :locals => {scribble:  scribble}%>
 <%end%>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#vote_<%=scribble.id%>")
```

vs

```
$("#vote_<%=@scribble.id%>")
```

you've set up `@scribble` not a local var called `scribble`

`@scribble` and `scribble` are not the same thing.

If you never assign a value to something called `scribble` - then it doesn't exist... and if you try to use in anywhere... then it will explode and tell you that it doesn't exist.

You will need to use `@scribble` everywhere unless you deliberately set up a local variable called `scribble`

eg:

```
  <%= render :partial=> "scribbles/vote", :locals => {scribble: @scribble}%>
```

Note. in *this* code you are *using* the variable called `@scribble` and setting aup a local variable (called `scribble`) for the partial to use.

the partial will now have access to `scribble`

Comment: also, then pass the `@scribble` variable into the partial so it can be referenced there as a local variable - partials should never use instance variables.

Comment: I tried it both ways, still does work and this is how i call partial:  <%= render :partial=> "scribbles/vote", :locals => {scribble: scribble}%> and i get it

Comment: Im guessing you are right, its probably because I'm passing instance variable to partial. But i'm doing so because I'm looping      <% @scribbles.each do |scribble| %>    <%= render :partial=> "scribbles/vote", :locals => {scribble: scribble}%> any ideas ?

Comment: where does the looping tie into the code you posted in the question? You have a vote action for a single scribble...

Comment: You have to use `@scribble`, not `scribble` when passing it to the partial too.

Comment: but I don't have '@scribble', because I'm dogging '@scribbles.each do |scribble|' 'render :partial => "vote", :locals => {scribble: scribble}'

Comment: Not in vote.js you are not. in vote.js.erb you are going directly from the main controller-action... where you have @scribble, but not scribble

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a local to a partial like this:

```
render(partial: 'path_to_partial', locals: { var_in_partial: var_in_current_scope })
```

So...

```
render(partial: 'scribbles/vote', locals: { scribble: scribble })
```

It'll be called `scribble` in the `_vote` partial, and we're passing in `scribble` from our current scope.

Alternately you could use `@scribble` which is defined in your controller and is available to all views/partials during your current request cycle.

Comment: this is the partial call <%= render :partial=> "scribbles/vote", :locals => {scribble: scribble}%> and all of the objects are displayed. but vote.js.erb doesn't get scribble object

Comment: And i can't really use scribble because of <% @scribbles.each do |scribble| %>

Comment: in Vote.html.erb only scribble works, in vote.js.erb neither works ;/